# Missing definition for TryAdd() in Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I am using example from tutorial https://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary
But I have problems with missing reference to `TryAdd`. Should I add some extra references for using this method? I did not find anything in documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.tryadd?view=net-5.0

```
var items = new Dictionary<string, int>();
// Part 1: add the string with value 1.
bool result = items.TryAdd("test", 1);
```

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error   CS1061  'Dictionary<string, int>' does not contain a definition for 'TryAdd' and no accessible extension method 'TryAdd' accepting a first argument of type 'Dictionary<string, int>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  CsharpTest  C:\path\to\file\Program.cs  672 Active

**UPDATE:** This method is for .NET 5 ang greater (I am using older framework)

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Are you using .net 5? `With this method (part of .NET 5)...`

Comment: Please check the [Applies To](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.tryadd#applies-to) table to verify that your .NET runtime supports the given operation.

Comment: `TryAdd` was added in .Net Core 2 so if you're using .Net Core 1 or .Net Framework (before .Net 5) then it will not be available.

Comment: @MartinCostello  Stefan : I am using 4.6.1 or 4.8 (Cannot turn to 5.0 on VS 17). I cannot see version of Framework for TryAdd() in docs. I assumed that it is also for almost all frameworks. This was probably the problem. Thank you.

Comment: What is difference in short between .NET and .NET framework (Applies to: table)?

Comment: @Ales100 .NET Framework and .NET Core are the past. .NET (without any suffix) 5 is new unified application development platform. .NET 6 is the up-coming version of the .NET.

Comment: Hmm... it's curious that this was closed with the reason _"not reproducible or was caused by typos"_. The question & answer are definitely helpful for anyone still using .NET framework...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The comments are semi-right. This method was introduced in .NET Core 2.0 and .NET Standard 2.1, so you need your target framework to be at least that. In particular, it does not exist on .NET Framework (any version) and it does exist on the latest .NET 5.

If you need it in an older runtime, you can write up an extension method (taken from [dotnet/runtime, System.Collections.Generic.CollectionExtensions](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/CollectionExtensions.cs)).

```cs
public static bool TryAdd<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, TKey key, TValue value)
{
    if (dictionary == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dictionary));
    }

    if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

It has worse performance characteristics than the instance method of `Dictionary<,>`, since it does a separate lookup first, but it's unlikely to be relevant.

Comment: I wonder if a `try-catch` around `dictionary.Add(key, value)` would not be more efficient than the additional lookup. If you know that you have to add it, it's unlikely that `ContainsKey` would return `true`, in that case it's redundant and a `try-catch` is the better choice. If you don't know it, maybe it's still more efficient.

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's a definite not. Exception handling is _extremely_ slow, uncomparably so to any normal operations. Here's a fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pgzu6k The difference is almost 100x in favour of normal execution flow. Also, performance notwithstanding, doing control flow with exceptions is very unidiomatic, and catching `ArgumentException` is a code smell - if an `ArgumentException` is thrown it means that the developer who passed an argument made a mistake, such exceptions shouldn't be thrown in running production code.

Comment: You can tweak the parameters in the fiddle. The non-exception way wins even if there is a single duplicate key, so if you set the second loop to go from `49_999`.

Comment: thanks for the fiddle. But it should be measured with benchmark.net, not in this way.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Sure thing, the differences in runtime were so stark I didn't bother with a proper bench, but for the sake of completeness: https://pastebin.com/mgJiqexz

The results on my PC are similar to the fiddle, 100x slower for the half hit/half miss case (BenchmarkStart = 25_000), 3x slower for 500 miss, 49_500 hit (BenchmarkStart = 49_500), a bit (5%) slower for 49_999 hit, 1 miss (BenchmarkStart = 49_999).

Comment: There is a surprise coming from this bench, though, namely that the Dictionary.Add under .NET Framework 4.8 seems to be much slower, while exception handling is faster. The exception version actually outperforms the standard one on .NET Framework 4.8 when there's only one miss! So in some sense, you were right, but only for .NET Framework.

Comment: you're right, just without an exception the TryCatch will outperform the ContainsKey, which is an edge case (where you dont need TryAdd but can use Add directly). But nice benchmarkl now, thanks :)

Comment: One thing to note: it doesn't only depend on how often an exception would be raised but also on how  well the key's `GetHashCode`  is implemented.